# How to add active class on specific “li” on multiple "ul" elements

Tags: javascript

I have three menu items and wish to add an active class the the specific li in the group (ul) when it is clicked.

I have managed to do it for one but I am battling to get it to work for each.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qx89dt0s/

JavaScript

```
var selector, elems, makeActive;

selector = '.nav li';

elems = document.querySelectorAll(selector);

makeActive = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
        elems[i].classList.remove('active');

    this.classList.add('active');
};

for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    elems[i].addEventListener('mousedown', makeActive);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Here's another way: https://jsfiddle.net/qx89dt0s/1/

Comment: @ChrisG thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to iterate over each `.nav` and do the same as previously done for the `li` within each `.nav`.

```
 // get all .nav  and convert into array, for latest
// browser use Array.from method
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.nav'))
// iterate over .nav elements
.forEach(function(ele) {
  // get all li within it
  var elems = ele.querySelectorAll('li');

  // define the function for updating
  var makeActive = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
      elems[i].classList.remove('active');
    this.classList.add('active');
  };

  // bind listener
  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    elems[i].addEventListener('mousedown', makeActive);
});
```

```js
[].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('.nav')).forEach(function(ele) {
  var elems = ele.querySelectorAll('li');

  var makeActive = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
      elems[i].classList.remove('active');
    this.classList.add('active');
  };

  for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++)
    elems[i].addEventListener('mousedown', makeActive);
});
```

```css
li.active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>

<ul class="nav">
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
</ul>
```